# If I fabricate a killstreak item that is not tradeable until X date, will the item become not tradeable permanently?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm trying to create a professional killstreak Original, however in order to do so, I needed to have two other specialized killstreak items. I did not have these, so I bought a couple cheap ones off the market. Of course, this made the items not tradeable for a week, so when I went to go fabricate the killstreak Original, I assumed correctly that it would not be tradeable for another week (as it says in the [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOUlv.jpg)).

But when I go to actually complete the fabricator, it comes with a message that says items will not be tradeable[image: items will not be tradable]

This leads me to believe that the item will not be tradeable at all, ever, when I complete the kit. So my question is, will the completed items from the kit still retain the original "not tradable until" date or should I just wait until they become tradable in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having personally done this myself, applying temporarily untradeable killstreak kits to a tradeable weapon transfers the trade date. Once the 7 days passes, your killstreak weapon is once again tradeable.

As Aaron mentioned, this wasn't always the case, but was patched during 2014's Smissmas update.

Answer (score 4):

**Correct me if I'm wrong here,** but the [December 22, 2014 patch](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/December_22,_2014_Patch) had fixed this:

> Crafting items that are marked as temporarily untradable will now yield temporarily untradable items instead of permanent

and Killstreak kits function the same way as crafting, so it would be reasonable to assume that this applies to killstreak kits as well.

A quick search on google will show no more questions about killstreak kits or other items being perma-uncraftable in a situation like this after December 22, the day of the patch.

Much of what has been said seems to imply that it retains the timer, but to be safe, just wait the seven days. It's always better safe than sorry.